# how to switch between two fragments by clicking on one of them?

Tags: android, android-fragments

suppose we have two fragments Frag1 and Frag2, now my question is how to switch between them by clicking on one of them using  "FragmentTransaction Replace"

this is my codes:

```
    public class Frags extends Fragment{

    private boolean mShowingBack = false;
    CardFrontFragment fr=new CardFrontFragment();
    CardBackFragment bk=new CardBackFragment();
    static View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            if (!mShowingBack)
            {
                return fr.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            }

            else
            {
                return bk.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            }


    }













    public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {
        public CardFrontFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front, container, false);

             view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                }




             });



             return view;
        }
    }


    public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {
        public CardBackFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          view=   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);



          view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                }




             });
             return view;
        }

    }










    public void flipCard() {
        if (mShowingBack) {
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            mShowingBack = !true;
            return;
        }
        mShowingBack = true;
        getChildFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
       .setCustomAnimations(
               R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out)
                .replace(R.id.container, this.bk)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();



}
```

and the problem:  container can not be found
logcat: No View found for id 0x7f600054(id/container)

so where i am wrong?
is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that you have not define fragment with id container in your layout file.

In fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout              
        android:id="@+id/container"   <!-- this part is missing that is why view cannot find -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also it seems like you did not inflate your layout in fragment onCreateView. This may also cause problem as system may not not which view it wants to create.

Comment: no, i have android:id="@+id/container" in xml layout, i managed to do this from outside of fragment, but inside i can NOT,

Comment: i solved the problem, i must use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager(), what a embarrassing!